# What does '#include <stdio.h>' really do in a C program

Tags: c, include, stdio

I am new to C programming, and as I was coding some simple 'Hello World' style programs, I noticed that in all of them, I included `#include<stdio.h>` at the top.

However, I'm not sure what this means exactly. I tried searching online and found that `stdio.h` is a file containing commands for the preprocessor, but what is a preprocessor? I thought that when I write code, I compile it, and my code transforms into a form that a computer can read, and then I can run it. Can someone explain to me the usage of this command?"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It looks for the `stdio.h` file and effectively copy-pastes it in the place of this `#include` statements. This file contains so-called function prototypes of functions such as `printf()`, `scanf()`, ... so that compiler knows what are their parameters and return values.

Comment: ok, so when I use printf the code that implement the printf is located in stdio.h? could I implement my version of printf (I know this is silly to do it, but lets say..)?

Comment: @Nat95: No, the code for the printf function is not in stdio.h, just the function definition. The linker later resolves this when linking to the standard library. You could absolutely write your own printf function.

Comment: +1 this is by far the best and simplest explanation of what the preprocessor effectively does with #include. Btw you can see this if you instruct the compiler/build system to keep preprocessed files.

Comment: To see the contents of the header files that would have been pasted above your actual code, compile your source code with `-E` option and you will be able to see the function prototypes that a particular header file contains. @Lucas: one typo mistake it's function prototype or declaration not function definition.

Comment: I would suggest mentioning that the filename means "Standard Input Output Header"

Answer (score 16):

The simplest explanation perhaps should be that your program **calls** or uses many functions whose code is not part of your program itself. For e.g. if you write "printf" in your code to print something, the compiler does not know what to do with that call.

stdio.h is the place where information for that printf resides.

**Update:**

Rather the **prototype** of printf function (name, return type and parameters) reside in stdio.h. That is all required in the compilation phase. The actual code of printf is included in the linking phase, which comes after compilation.

The include statement basically inserts all function prototypes BEFORE the actual compilation. Hence the name preprocessor.

**Update 2:**

Since the question focused on include statement (and the OP also asked about writing definition of functions himself, another important aspect is if it is written like (note the angular brackets)

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

The preprocessor assumes, it is a standard library header and looks in the system folders first where the compiler has been installed.

If instead a programmer defines a function by himself and place the .h file in the current working directory, he would use (note the double quotes)

```
#include "stdio.h"
```

[Following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx) illustrates it and the behavior is portable across all platforms.

Comment: ok, so when I use printf the code that implement the printf is located in stdio.h? could I implement my version of printf (I know this is silly to do it, but lets say..)?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Please understand that my above answer is oversimplified. But it is the right concept to start from. As we go deep, you might see much details. I actually wrote a newer version of printf in my first programming course of BSc more than a decade ago. That involved directly accessed the video memory and writing on specific addresses via pointers.

Comment: To clarify, there are .h files and there are .c files. h files only contain function prototypes i.e. tell what a function name, return type and parameters are. The actual definition is located in linking phase, which comes after compilation.

Answer (score 1):

It tells the compiler to use functions, structures, macros and etc from file sdtio.h, which represents a part of glibc(or whatever is the standart C library you got). Compiler also adds record to the output executable "to-link list", that it should be linked to standart C library.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor directives in a source code are the statements which are processed before the compilation of a program, after this step the source code is converted into the expanded source code as it now contains the references to the functions which are already defined in the Standard C Library(or any other) like printf, scanf, putw, getchar etc.
The stdio.h is a file with ".h" extension that contains the prototypes (not definition) of standard input-output functions used in c.